# How do I set up a custom build step in Visual Studio 6?

Tags: visual-c++-6

Unfortunately it looks like for various reasons I'm going to have to use Visual Studio 6 instead of a newer version of VS.

It's been a long time since I've used it. I'm looking through its menus and don't see any obvious way to set up any custom build steps (pre-build, post-build, pre-link... anything would help actually).

Can anyone give me instructions on how to set up steps like this?

Comment: which reasons force you to use VS 6 out of curiosity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your project, then open the Project Settings screen (Project → Settings or ALT-F7).  Alternatively, right click on a file in the FileView and select Settings.

From the Project Settings screen, go to the General tab and check "Always use custom build step".  This means that the file you just chose will be an input file for a custom build step.  From the "Custom Build" tab you can then give the commands to run and specify what files will be generated.

For pre-link, post-build and such, select an executable (or library) from the Project Settings screen.  Then use the little arrow button to scroll to the rightmost tabs.  From there you'll find the Pre-link and Post-build steps.

It's quite simple, really, I'm sure this is enough to get you started.